# Finding original sample size from result percentage (sales from returned units)

Tags: natural-deduction

A local company published percentages of returned units for electronic components and one of the numbers raised the suspicion that number of sold units could be very low to cause such a high percentage of returns ( 31.7 ).

I started thinking, if I know the returned percentage, I should be able to calculate what is the minimum number of total units for such a result to be possible ( you cannot return half units or sell partial units so it has to be a whole number ).

Yes, the problem was quite quickly solved by an excel sheet just bruteforcing the problem but this piqued me.

**So: how do I calculate the minimum number of units X to be sold, at least, for the return percentage to be possible to be 31,7.**

Multiples of 1000 are of course all correct answers but are there others? ( i'm assuming the number could be rounded, but for simplicity's sake, let's assume it's not and it's an exact number ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $317$ is a prime number, $317/1000$ is in lowest terms. That means the only fractions
$$
\frac{x}{y} = \frac{31.7}{100}
$$
with integers $x$ and $y$ will have $y$ a multiple of $1000$.

If the percentage (after moving the decimal point to get to an integer) has no factors of $2$ or $5$ the same argument will work. If it does have those factors, divide by them to find the fraction in lowest terms. That will tell you the minimum possible number of units.

For example, if the return percentage was $18$, writing
$$
\frac{x}{y} = \frac{18}{100}  = \frac{9}{50}
$$
as a fraction in lowest terms 
says that the minimum possible number of units is $50$.

Comment: Thank you, this explains why the only solutions I found were multiples of 1000. I'm not quite following the rest of your explanation. If the percentage was something else, would there be a way to calculate the minimum number? Say the return percentage was 18 to make it simple.

Comment: You're welcome. See my edit.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a bunch for this clarification it all makes sense now :)

Comment: In the example i mentioned first we surmised the real number had been rounded so we went with 31,6-something and ended up with an answer that sounds reasonable being 41 units sold and 13 returned, still a huge number but a lot more probable as we suspect a mistake purchase due to labelling being the culprit.